# Selecting tuning parameters with caret using standard deviation of custom metric

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm using caret with custom fitting metric, but I need to maximize not just this metric but lower bound of it's confidence interval. So I'd like to maximize something like `mean(metric) - k * stddev(metric)`. I know how to do this manually, but is there a way to tell caret to automatically select best parameters using this function?

Comment: I've flagged this question as off-topic, so please migrate it to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can define your own selection metric through the "summaryFunction" parameter of your "trainControl" object and then with the "metric" parameter of your call to `train()`. Details on this are pretty well documented in the "Alternate Performance Metrics" section on caret's model tuning page: http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/training.html

I don't think you gave enough information for anyone to write exactly what you're looking for, but here is an example using the code from the twoClassSummary function:

```
> library(caret)
> data(Titanic)
> 
> #an example custom function
> roc <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
+   require(pROC)
+   if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == levels(data[, "obs"]))) 
+     stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
+   rocObject <- try(pROC:::roc(data$obs, data[, lev[1]]), silent = TRUE)
+   rocAUC <- if (class(rocObject)[1] == "try-error") 
+     NA
+   else rocObject$auc
+   out <- c(rocAUC, sensitivity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[1]), specificity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[2]))
+   names(out) <- c("ROC", "Sens", "Spec")
+   out
+ }
> 
> #your train control specs
> tc <- trainControl(method="cv",classProb=TRUE,summaryFunction=roc)
> #yoru model with selection metric specificed
> train(Survived~.,data=data.frame(Titanic),method="rf",trControl=tc,metric="ROC")
32 samples
 4 predictors
 2 classes: 'No', 'Yes' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validation (10 fold) 

Summary of sample sizes: 28, 29, 30, 30, 28, 28, ... 

Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  ROC    Sens  Spec  ROC SD  Sens SD  Spec SD
  2     0.9    0.2   0.25  0.175   0.35     0.425  
  4     0.85   0.4   0.6   0.211   0.459    0.459  
  6     0.875  0.35  0.6   0.212   0.412    0.459  

ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2.
```

Comment: Hi, would you be able to show me how to use this summaryFunction to select a classifier based only on specificity? I want this because my data for positive events is very rare.

Comment: Just use `metric="Spec"`

Answer (score 0):

There is more basic example in the caret's help for train function:

```
madSummary <- function (data,
                        lev = NULL,
                        model = NULL) {
  out <- mad(data$obs - data$pred, 
             na.rm = TRUE)  
  names(out) <- "MAD"
  out
}

robustControl <- trainControl(summaryFunction = madSummary)
marsGrid <- expand.grid(degree = 1, nprune = (1:10) * 2)

earthFit <- train(medv ~ .,
                  data = BostonHousing, 
                  method = "earth",
                  tuneGrid = marsGrid,
                  metric = "MAD",
                  maximize = FALSE,
                  trControl = robustControl)
```