# Using [R] packages caret and gbm: "Error in vector(type, length) : vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'NULL'"

Tags: r, vector, r-caret, gbm

I'm trying to train a boosting model on a data frame, using the Caret and gbm packages in R. I've been able to build models successfully with default parameters; however, I continue to hit this error, when I attempt to customize the summary function:

```
Error in vector(type, length) : 
  vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'NULL'.
```

This is the first question I've posted, as I'm usually able to root up info to solve the problem. In this case, I can't seem to find a similar issue.

The following code is intended to reproduce the error. Let me know if it doesn't, or if I should include additional info, as I'm more than happy to do so.

**System.info:**
**sysname**: Windows
**release**: 7 x64
**version**: build 7601, Service Pack 1
**version.string**: R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
**system**: x86_64, mingw32

```
library(plyr)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(response = rnorm(100), predictor1 = rnorm(100), predictor2 = rnorm(100))

aeSummary <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
    out <- abs(data$obs-data$pred)
    names(out) <- "AE"
    out
 }

modelFit <- train(response ~ ., 
              data = example,
              method = "gbm", 
              tuneGrid = data.frame(n.trees = 5, 
                                    interaction.depth = 5, 
                                    shrinkage = 0.05, 
                                    n.minobsinnode = 6),
              metric = "AE", 
              maximize = FALSE, 
              trControl = trainControl(
                      summaryFunction = aeSummary))
```

Comment: See the second answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759594/selecting-tuning-parameters-with-caret-using-standard-deviation-of-custom-metric). That seems to be exactly what you are trying to do. Your function works with `out <- mean(abs(data$obs - data$pred))` because the summary function has to return a single value.

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot! It's returning a vector, as is... makes sense. You're also right in that that's the exact example I was using to model my own, further exasperating my confusion. Thanks for the help - any idea how I close out the question?

Comment: You should be able to [delete the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions). If not I could flag the question as a duplicate or you can answer the question yourself and accept that answer.